# How to prevent 'Error creating assembly archive distribution: A zip file cannot include itself'

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi module project and I want to make a zip with all sources (and other files). I use [`maven-assemble-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

I found a way with [`dependencySet`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly#class_dependencySet), but I do not want add all my module sources (and later javadoc, too) as dependencies. I tried to use [`moduleSet`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly#class_moduleSet), but I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (make-zip) on project test-distribution: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive distribution: A zip file cannot include itself -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (make-zip) on project test-distribution: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive distribution: A zip file cannot include itself
```

My pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-zip</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assemble/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>test</finalName> 
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My assembly descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">

    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
             <sources>
                 <outputDirectory>/Sources</outputDirectory>
             </sources>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

With `dependencySet` I could fix that problem with option [`useProjectArtifact`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly#class_dependencySet), but I found no option for `moduleSet`. Is there any way to exclude the current project's build?

Comment: I suspect that your configuration is creating the zip file inside one of the folders that you are trying to compact. The zip works as this, it creates the file then add the archives to it, therefore the error. This is just a guess, just to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to [exclude](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_moduleSet) current project's build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">

    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*:test-distribution</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <sources>
                <outputDirectory>/Sources</outputDirectory>
            </sources>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```