# Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive null: A tar file cannot include itself

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use `maven-assembly-plugin` to package my project into a `.tar` file.

I've added the following plugin to my `pom.xml` file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/myProjectConf.xml</descriptor>
                <finalName>my-project-${version}</finalName>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.zip</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.tar</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

`myProjectConf.xml` has the following content:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/3.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/3.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-3.0.0.xsd">
    <formats>
        <format>tar</format>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>README*</include>
                <include>LICENSE*</include>
                <include>NOTICE*</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/packagedFiles</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/test</directory>
            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/packagedFiles</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/packagedFiles</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

However, I'm getting;

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) on project job-manager: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive null: A tar file cannot include itself. -> [Help 1]
```

I looked at this question [How to prevent 'Error creating assembly archive distribution: A zip file cannot include itself'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945526/how-to-prevent-error-creating-assembly-archive-distribution-a-zip-file-cannot) that's similar and I therefore added `<excludes>` to my project, as you can see above.

Nothing changed with the error message though.

Comment: First of all, you're using a very old version... you should upgrade to 3.0.0. Then you have a `<fileSet>` with no `<directory>`, not sure what this does but maybe it includes everything under the basedir, and that would be the problem. Also, `<excludes>` does not exist, so that configuration is ignored completely, and `<descriptor>` was removed, use `<descriptors>` instead.

Comment: 1.I upgraded my version to 3.0.0 2.I removed the `<fileset>` with no `<directory>`. I still have the same problem

Comment: Please post the updated POM and assembly descriptor. Make sure you run `mvn clean package` as well.

Comment: I've updated my post. `maven clean package` works but `maven assembly:assembly` doesn't.

Comment: Ah yes, that is normal then. `mvn assembly:assembly` is deprecated for long and `assembly:single` should be used. But always prefer to use the `package` phase...

Comment: How can I specify a file by name? I want something like this: 
`<fileSet>
            <name>my-package-${version}.jar</name>
               <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/packagedFiles</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>`

Comment: Look into `<files>` instead of `<fileSets>`, see here also http://stackoverflow.com/a/41064834/1743880

Comment: Please Update the version of the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) you are using cause 2.2-beta-5 is really from an ancient time. Current version is 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by adding "maven-clean-plugin".

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I get this error when I try it: Could not find goal 'clean' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0 among available goals